# Why does this undefined check not work with a find function?

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain why in the following example, variable `z` has type `number`, but within the call `f1(x.y)`, `x.y` has type `number | undefined`

```
const f1 = (value: number) => !!value;

const f2 = (x: { y: number | undefined}): void => {
    if (x.y === undefined || !isFinite(x.y)) {
        throw new Error('Not a number');
    }

    const z = x.y; // z & x.y has type number 
    ['stuff', 'here'].find(item => f1(x.y)); // x.y has type number | undefined
};
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgRhgXhgCgG4EMA2BXAUwC4Yw8BbAIwICcBKFAPhgEIXt8CBuAKB9Eiw4AJhToAHiQDeMAJ4kyVWjAA+MPGAAmBOAEswBTQF86JDCF2amMKTxj2YuuBIB0slMlQbteg1ZVqLLoQAGL6ulAEaOJudAy2DokwUAAWNCAA7qQEWQCiNOk0aADkAHIgsFikFNQ0xXS8iUZ8iQLQMABeYjGyjQ4A2sXQeHBwxQA0MMUptATFALouvppoEQTk1nDRsQ08RrxAA)

Comment: `number` != `number | undefined` they're different types. You'll have to cast it

Comment: Why does making a temporary variable fix it? Why does the control flow based type analysis works in the later but not in the former?

Comment: May or may not be interesting but this slightly simper example works and I'm struggling to spot what the important difference is: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZjAvDAFADwFwwN4wJ5ZgCuAtgEYCmATjAD4xFgAmFcAlmBUzAL4CUSAHw4AUDHEw2CdADo8SRMkYt2nJgOxiJ2qAAsqIAO4xOxgKJUDVFACIAKhWg2+Abi3ieI9zFCRYALyQYNDkXGAB6cJg9NghJOIBDE1JKKhEeNxEOKGo4BOAKGABJAEFRbQJk8mo6BmZWDi43TxFfaHgAJiD0LFKBRGFNbSlUEPlFJXrVLg1vHX0jEwpzSxBre0coZzdtFu02gKCxsMjo3Vj4mCTiarSMoA

Comment: > number != number | undefined they're different types. You'll have to cast it 

@Liam Casting is a crutch to bypass type checking :) It should be possible to solve this with type checking to make sure undefined isn't passed to something that only accepts numbers (as done in my whyDoesThisWork function without a cast). My guess is that this somehow relates to javascript scopes?

Comment: @Liam I think the question is really looking to ask why is `valueAsVariable` `number` but  in the first example `functionUsingNumber(objectWithMaybeNumber.value)` `objectWithMaybeNumber.value` has type `number | undefined`

Comment: @blub I've made a substantial edit, I think you should be able to dump it if you aren't happy with it, I got the feeling this could be clarified slightly

Comment: @Liam can you show that in a playground example? The point here is that the check against `undefined` should be able to act as a type guard

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it is simpler!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really liked this question and done some research, and learnt something. As OP mentioned it has to do with closure, specifically the callback. Please read my comments in the code below where I try to explain things as they come.

```ts
const f1 = (value: number) => !!value;

const f2 = (x: { y: number | undefined}): void => {
    if (x.y === undefined || !isFinite(x.y)) {
        throw new Error('Not a number');
    }

    // Here, you have ensured here that type of z is not changing
    const z = x.y;

    // `x.y` is mutable, 
    // As jcalz correctly mentioned in the comment, 
    // the compiler does not know that the `find` function executes the 
    // callback synchronously and immediately, and it is expensive
    // to check if anyone has altered its type elsewhere before the 
    // callback was executed. So, it can't
    // guarantee that the type of `x.y` stays number
    // hence, Typescript expands `x.y` back to `number | undefined`
    ['stuff', 'here'].find(item => f1(x.y));

    
    // This however knows type isn't changing
    ['stuff', 'here'].find(item => f1(z));

    // However, this works because Typescript optimistically thinks
    // the function, in our case `find`, does not have a side effect
    // (referring the article noted below)
    f1(x.y);

    // In a parallel universe, where `find` is 
    // asynchronous like `timeout`,
    // and executes the callback sometime later
    // and we had the following line here
    x.y = undefined
    // Since the `find` function, in our parallel universe, 
    // would call the callback
    // after we have assigned `x.y` as `undefined`
    // it makes sense to expand the type in the callback within the find
    // function back to number | undefined
};
```

Here is an interesting article on this. Really good read: https://herringtondarkholme.github.io/2017/02/04/flow-sensitive/

Comment: Great to have an article on this one

Comment: The possibly-canonical issue for this is [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) ("Trade-offs in Control Flow Analysis"), with [microsoft/TypeScript#11498](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11498) ("Annotate immediately-invoked functions for inlining flow control analysis") as a proposal to address cases like this... not that there's been much progress here.

Comment: I read that exact issue while researching, quite a few thing to learn from there. The article that mentioned also talks about a keyword `immediate` as a proposal to work out this issues... which is in the simiilar tone as the issue I guess

Comment: Btw, I'd say that the "optimistic" part is assuming that the narrowing of `x.y` persists after the callback, but the behavior here is "pessimistic": inside the callback the compiler thinks that `x.y`'s narrowing is possibly no longer applicable, since it doesn't know that `find()` runs its callback immediately and synchronously, and doesn't have the bandwidth to check that nobody ever re-widens `x.y` (like [this](https://tsplay.dev/vwjE7W)).

Comment: Ah, of course, I misinterpreted the optimistic part. Let me edit that.

Comment: Thanks, the article is very insightful!

Comment: @jcalz I have updated the answer, to make more sense. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that inside of the arrow function the compiler is not certain that the type narrowing is still valid.

```
const f1 = (value: number) => !!value;

const f2 = (x: { y: number | undefined}): void => {
    if (x.y === undefined || !isFinite(x.y)) {
        throw new Error('Not a number');
  }
  // z is `number`, so use `z` again in the arrow function to "keep" the type narrowing
  const z = x.y;
  ['stuff', 'here'].find(item => f1(z));
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgRhgXhgCgG4EMA2BXAUwC4Yw8BbAIwICcBKFAPhgEIXt8CBuAKB9Eiw4AJhToAHiQDeMAJ4kyVWjAA+MPGAAmBOAEswBTQF86JDCF2amMKTxj2YuuBIB0slMlQbteg1ZVqLLoQAGL6ulAEaOJudAy2DokwUAAWNCAA7qQEWQCiNOk0aADkAHIgsFikFNQ0xXS8iUZ2DgLQMABeYjGyjQ4A2sXQeHBwxQA0MMUptATFALouvppoEQTk1ohoHXG8RlxAA)

Comment: Interesting - I wasn't aware that type guards worked in this scope-specific way. Good to know. I've not been able to find anything in any docs/issues relating to this.